# sign up/registration forms PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, registration

I am trying to create a basic 'registration' form for events that are on my website.

I've read the w3schools PHP and SQL tutorials but am still struggling to understand how and where the data is stored and submitted.

I used the `method="post"` and `action="test.php"` attributes but upon clicking `<input type="submit">` the user is taken to a blank page (`www.myurl.com/php/test.php`).

I am wanting the user to remain on the same page after clicking submit but for their data to be properly validated and stored/sent to a table on my server (MySQL?) so that attendees/customers can be printed out before the event.

Comment: remove action file `test.php` and post your PHP code along with HTML form with your question, there is nothing much to say before looking at your code

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems like you are quite new to back end, I suggest you watch some online PHP tutorials:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UaWN7gObv-c&list=PLlkGN-8wjPHV41Y12LFD8uttbAd1d_ohe&ab_channel=AdamKhoury
   Especially the one above...
2. You really need to post your what you have so far before people can really make an honest attempt to help you.

**My Understanding of your problem:**
It seems like you're having trouble redirecting users to the same page after a form submit to the server. Without AJAX you can usually put a `header();` function at the end of script back to original page. 
It can be accomplished like this:
`header('location: example.php ')`
Where "example.php" is the page you want to redirect to.

---

It would also be a good time to educate yourself on Website Cybersecurity, since you're dealing with the server.http://php.net/manual/en/security.php